# Facing Integration Issues with Hikvision Network Camera in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, camera, hikvision

I'm currently developing a project using C# and ASP.NET MVC, and I need assistance with integrating a Hikvision Network Camera.

If anyone has experience or expertise with Hikvision integrations, specifically within the context of C# and ASP.NET MVC, could you please lend me a hand? Any insights, workarounds, or advice you could provide would be invaluable to me at this stage.

Comment: This is way too vague at the moment. What *specific* problem are you facing? Please show relevant code.

Comment: There is far to little information to go on, you should at least do some preliminary research. Start by reading the documentation for your camera, it should at the very least show what protocol you can use. RTSP? GigE vision?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.